# re-tire elastic search multi table/index search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, tire

I' trying to figure out what would be the best way to do a multi table search with elastic.co.

In particular, I was wondering if I could add more indexes to this search method.

**Chapter.rb**

```
def self.search(params)
      fields = [:title, :description, :content ]
      **tables** = [Chapter.index_name, Book.index_name]
      tire.search(**tables**, {load: true,page: params[:page], per_page: 5}) do
        query do
          boolean do
            must { string params[:q], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:q].present?
          end
        end

        highlight *fields, :options => { :tag => '<strong>' }
      end
```

The above example works without the **Tables**. How to make it work with the tables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're adding more indexes then you are moving away from it being a model-centric search. That's probably fine as I guess you'll be handling the search results differently on account of them being from different indexes.

In which case I think you can do:

```
Tire.search([Chapter.index_name, Book.index_name], 
  page: params[:page],
  ... etc ...
) do
  query do
    ... etc ...
  end
end
```

It does mean that you won't be able to do stuff like `load: true` because you've moved outside of knowing what model to load the results for.

From digging around in the code ([here](https://github.com/karmi/retire/blob/master/lib/tire/model/search.rb)) it looks like you might be able to specify multiple indexes even for a model-centric search. Something like:

```
tire.search({
  index: [Chapter.index_name, Book.index_name],
  load: true,
  ... etc ...
```

I haven't tried it though and I'm doubtful as to whether it will work - again because of not being able to load the results into a specific model once multiple indexes are involved.